# How to structure a CA directory for usage with OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority

If you want to set up your own CA, you will most probably create a dedicated folder with appropriate rights where you keep all the necessary files, such as the `serial` and the `index.txt`.

Additionally, you might want to keep all received CSRs, and all signed and published certificates. Also there is most probably a `.config` file for OpenSSL that you want to store inside that folder.

Now my question is, whether there are any best practices or whether there is any common sense in how to structure that CA directory? Should everything just be kept inside one single folder, or does it make more sense to use subfolders? If so, for which items would you create specific subfolders? ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now organized the `ca` folder as follows:

```
ca
+- certs             # Here, the created certificates are stored
+- private           # Permissions locked down to 0700
|  +- ca.key
+- ca.cert
+- index.txt
+- serial
+- openssl.config
```

I am looking forward to other ideas, anyway.